# what is the Use of this Json utils?

Tags: c++, json

In my case,  After polling all the module this `setDocumentRoot` getting called what this exactly this function will do?

```
void RflJsonUtils::setDocumentRoot(Trace & GTRACE,const char *Root) {

    setHtmlRoot(Root);
    setJsonRoot();
    setRfljsRoot();
    setPdaRoot();
    return;

}
```

Comment: Please, don't add random tags in your question

Comment: Not related to the question, but `return` isn't needed in this case.

Comment: from where is `RflJsonUtils`?